# to check whether the list of arrays has same value

Tags: c#

I have a list of all integer array in which i want to check whether the list has same value i.e -1.

for ex.

```
int[] intk= {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1};
int[] intl = { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 };
List<int[]> lst = new List<int[]>();
lst.Add(intk);
lst.Add(intl);
```

how to find lst has only -1 only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flatten your list with `SelectMany` and then check if all are same:

```
int value = -1;
bool allSame = lst.SelectMany(a => a).All(i => i == value);
```

Comment: @Tigran thanks! Your answer is correct for single array, but there is list of arrays in question

Answer (score 0):

You can check that using the `.All(...)` extension method bundled with LINQ.

In order to create a list with both array items, you should use `.AddRange(...)` and the `T` parameter of `List<T>` should be `int` instead of `int[]`:

```
int[] intk= {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1};
int[] intl = { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 };
List<int> lst = new List<int>();
lst.AddRange(intk);
lst.AddRange(intl);
```

And now you'll be able to use `.All(...)`:

```
bool result = lst.All(item => item == 1);
```

...or:

```
bool result = lst.All(item => item == -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work if you want to check to any same values not only -1.

```
var l = lst.SelectMany(_ => _);
bool areSame = l.All(_ => l.FirstOrDefault() == _);
```